# Using echo instead of die()

Tags: php

I often see something like this when using mysql:

> mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

I see what this is for. What can I do that the error is printed but the script is running to the end?

I think of something like this:

> mysql_query($sql) or echo mysql_error();

Would that work?

Comment: This is not appropriate question for SO. just give it a try and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `echo` is a language construct and therefore cannot be used in this manner.

`print`, however, <del>*is*</del> still isn't a function but it can be used in this way... somehow. Don't ask me, PHP is just weird sometimes.

```
mysql_query($sql) or print(mysql_error());
```

It should be noted, however, that you would be better switching to [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), and this includes a much more robust error handling system (provided you enable it with `setAttribute` correctly)

Comment: print _is not_ a function. It's just allowed as expression. (≠ statement)

Answer (score 0):

The `die()` is usually used because you cannot work with the query (and it will cause notices/errors being thrown).

What you can do is something like this

```
$query = mysql_query($sql);
if ($query === FALSE) {
    // do something with mysql_error()
} else {
    //regular code for fetching rows
}
```

This way if the query fails the `if()` will be true and you can log/print the error and continue from after the part, where the query was used.

Did you see the red big box in the manual on all pages concerning `mysql_*` functions?

> **Warning**
>   This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API guide](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) and [related FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.

If you're writing new code and want it to be easily maintainable in the future, you should consider the warning.

Comment: thank you. This works for me. 
I know mysql is deprecated, but it works for the things I need. And I will change in near future.